# NHibernate: modify XML/XDoc mappings to work with SQLite in-memory database

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a project using NHibernate with XML mappings.

I'm modifying my integration test infrastructure so I can use an in-memory SQLite database rather than the SQL Server 2005 database we use in production.

However, I have a property mapping in one of my types that is not supported by SQLite.  The column has a type of XML, and the entity property has a type of XDoc.

When I try to create my schema to set up my database:

```
SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(configuration);
se.Create(true, true);
```

I get the error:
    System.ArgumentException : Dialect does not support DbType.Xml

I know that I can modify my mappings at runtime, and that's what I'm attempting to do.  But I can't figure out what needs to be done for this specific case so I can get this to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try subclassing the SQLite dialect class (and maybe also the corresponding NHibernate driver class) to map the XML types to some other type that SQLite can handle.

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure if the entity will be hydrated properly, but that gets me past the mapping problem.  I'm surprised at this rather opaque solution for a problem that I would expect to be more prevalent.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this would depend on the actual in-memory representation of the parameter values being compatible with whatever DbType you set in the driver. But the driver I think would be able to convert the parameter value also if required. But that might not help for hydrating. Not sure... If it doesn't work and you can try to describe a reasonable NHibernate feature, you can suggest it at https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH/